# how to set php.validate.executablePath in vscode ubuntu?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am new to linux. I am using XAMPP in ubuntu. I want to set `php.validate.executablePath` in the VS Code settings. I tried and didin't find any solution. My `htocs` folder is in `/opt/lampp/htdocs`.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't go wrong, the PHP path should be:

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php
```

Therefore you should set:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "/opt/lampp/bin/php"
```